# e^z is rational function or not

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that all rational functions are meromorphic. And a function is meromorphic when it doesn't have essential singularities. From this can I conclude that e^z is not a rational function? I'm totally confused. Please help.

Comment: One needs to be careful with the domain in which we say a function is [meromorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function).  All rational functions are meromorphic in the complex plane $\mathbb C$, and the exponential function $e^z$ is also meromorphic there (indeed, it is entire).  The essential singularity of the exponential function occurs at $\infty$ in the "extended" complex plane, and rational functions lack an essential singularity there.  So the gist of the argument works, but needs some care in locating the essential singularity.

Comment: Can you tell me whether e^z is rational or not?

Comment: As the Answer by @LordShark explains, the exponential function  $e^z$ has an essential singularity "at infinity", while a rational function does not.  So the exponential function is not rational.  Are you familiar with adding the point "at infinity" to the complex plane?  Are you familiar with the notion of essential singularity?

Comment: Now I understand. I skip the part of extended complex plane.

Answer (score 5):

$e^z$ **does** have an essential singularity, at $\infty$
(i.e. $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at zero).

What is the case is that a meromorphic on  function on the Riemann sphere $\Bbb C_\infty$
is a rational function. The exponential function is meromorphic on $\Bbb C$
but not on $\Bbb C_\infty$.